# is the order of uevents preserved till delivery to userspace?

Tags: linux-kernel, udev

Presuming that on a multicore system, the sequence in which kobj_uevent()'s are issued is ensured (i.e. they are either issued in a single kernel thread or serialized by some other way), is it guaranteed that the events will be delivered to the (single) userspace process listening on the netlink socket in the same order?

If the answer is yes, then what is the purpose of SEQNUM?

Answer (score 0):

No the events are delivered to the userspace process in the order of the seqnum.

Comment: How can the answer be both "No" and "the events are delivered to the userspace process in the order of the seqnum" at the same time?

The way I understand it, if the order of `kobj_uevent()` calls is ensured by the caller, then `SEQNO` is guaranteed to be in ascending order. Then, if the events are delivered to the userspace in the `SEQNO` order, then they are also delivered in the order of issue.

And then the question still stands - what is the purpose of `SEQNO`?